# While executing the below code i'm getting this 'TypeError: img is not a numerical tuple'

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

```
    import cv2
    ram_frames=30
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    def get_image():
          cap = cam.read()
          return cap
    for i in xrange(ramp_frames):
              temp = get_image()
    image = get_image()
    cv2.imwrite('bin/color.jpg',image)
```

The error i'm getting is :

```
File "C:\modules\imlib.py", line 1035, in __init__
    self.imin = self.WinWebCam()
  File "C:\modules\imlib.py", line 1125, in WinWebCam
    cv2.imwrite('bin/color.jpg',image)
TypeError: img is not a numerical tuple
```

I have done everything right i didn't change anything the code which when executed in a seperate program it's not showing any error but when run inside my code it's showing error. The code i copied is from [this link](https://codeplasma.com/2012/12/03/getting-webcam-images-with-python-and-opencv-2-for-real-this-time/)

Comment: You did not even find your typo at line 2. Please read your code more carefully befor posting it here. You could have easily found this error by yourself. Now you won't have that feeling of success that is so important for learning. You have give that opportunity away because you were lazy :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have changed the code while copying. Obviously, `cam.read()` returns a tuple. From the documentation:

```
Python: cv2.VideoCapture.read([image]) → retval, image
```

You are returning the whole tuple of `retval` and `image`, while the example only returns the second part of it (the image). So your `image` variable in line 9 contains the complete tuple that is returned by `read()` while the example only returns the second part of it. `imwrite` then fails because it does not expect a tuple as argument.

Try changing your code like this:

```
def get_image():
      _, cap = cam.read()
      return cap
```

or, even better,

```
def get_image():
    return cam.read()[1]
```

Additionally, you have misspelled the variable `ramp_frames` as `ram_frames` in line 2.

Comment: while your fix should be fine, your explanation is not.
The error states: img is not a numerical tuple.
The image is expected to be a numerical tuple which his input is not as it is a boolean. cam.read() returns a boolean for success and an image (the expected numerical tuple).

Comment: No, he feeds the tuple into `imwrite` which is the problem. The error indicates that the argument is of a bad type (`TypeError`).

Comment: And what kind of touple is this?
And why would the error message say that img is not a tuple if he puts a tuple in?

Comment: Try running this code: `def VideoCapture(n): return True, "IMGObjectSubstitute" ; def get_image(): cap = VideoCapture(0); return cap; print get_image()` (sorry code examples do not work well in comments).

Comment: sry my python knowledge is limited. I assumed it works the same as in Lua. And an image is indeed a numerical tuple, at least most times. so it made sense :) Didn't know that tuple is actually a special thing in python.

Comment: Ah ok. No, there are some differences to Lua;-)

Comment: Also how the above code when used with a webcam adjusts itself to surrounding brightness?? i didn't understand that

Comment: I'm not too familiar with OpenVC, but I think the program records some frames to give the camera time to adjust the image brightness to ambient light levels. You could verify this by saving all those images and compare them, for example by pasting each one in a new image layer in GIMP.

Answer (score 0):

if np.any( initial == None):
   #your code
It will definitely work for you. The error in this code because initial is treated as a numpy array.

I initialized initial with None in my program