# opencv package python numpy

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import math

webcam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
frame = webcam.read()
webcam.release()
detector =cv2.CascadeClassifier("xml/frontal_face.xml")
scale_factor=1.2
min_neighbors=5
min_size=(30,30)
biggest_only= True
flags= cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
#print type(frame)
flags =cv2.CASCADE_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT | cv2.CASCADE_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH if biggest_only else cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE

face = detector.detectMultiScale(
        frame,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags=flags)
```

error:

> File "C:\Users\DELL\workspace\facedetect\detect.py", line 23, in 
>       flags=flags)
>   TypeError: image is not a numerical tuple

Comment: you should consider rephrasing the title of the question

Answer (score 1):

If you see [THIS LINK](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html), it states that the line `webcam.read()` returns two values.

You should consider changing the line to something like this:

```
ret, frame = webcam.read()
```

The **frame** variable returns the image frame obtained from the video.

The **ret** variable returns a boolean (True/False) indicating if the frame has been read correctly or not.

Comment: You can also check [THIS ANSWER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36153963/while-executing-the-below-code-im-getting-this-typeerror-img-is-not-a-numeric/36154096#36154096) for an alternative way to code.