# Using python with opencv to achieve image splicing

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

There are two pictures, they have the same area such as:

[image]

[image]

I want to splice two images.My code is as follows

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

leftImg = cv2.imread('D:\\1.jpg')
rightImg = cv2.imread('D:\\2.jpg')
leftgray=cv2.cvtColor(leftImg,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
rightgray=cv2.cvtColor(rightImg,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

hessian=400
surf=cv2.SURF(hessian)
kp1,des1=surf.detectAndCompute(leftgray,None)
kp2,des2=surf.detectAndCompute(rightgray,None)


FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE=0
indexParams=dict(algorithm=FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE,trees=5)
searchParams=dict(checks=50)
flann=cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(indexParams,searchParams)
matches=flann.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)

h,w=leftgray.shape[:2]
good=[]
for m,n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.7*n.distance:
        good.append(m)

src_pts = np.array([ kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good])
dst_pts = np.array([ kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good])
H=cv2.findHomography(src_pts,dst_pts)
dst_corners=cv2.warpPerspective(leftgray,H,(w*2,h))

dst_corners[0:h,w:w*2]=rightgray
cv2.imwrite('tiled.jpg',dst_corners)
cv2.imshow('tiledImg',dst_corners)

cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But I got a mistake,that is

```
dst_corners=cv2.warpPerspective(leftgray,H,(w*2,h))

TypeError: M is not a numerical tuple
```

what should I do?Please tell me how to implement the function,thank you very much!

Comment: do you know how to achieve copy move forgery for fonts(character/digit) in images using python ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you print the homography matrix, you'll understand your mistake. Change this line to.

```
dst_corners=cv2.warpPerspective(leftgray,H[0],(w*2,h))
```

Comment: @chaoCN i want achieve image splicing, i tried your code but i get following error     surf=cv2.SURF(hessian)
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'SURF'

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36153963/while-executing-the-below-code-im-getting-this-typeerror-img-is-not-a-numeric) you should change the line in

```
H, mask =cv2.findHomography(src_pts,dst_pts)
```

and separate the outputs